# I am looking for help trying to make a views to list users with an associated location

Tags: views

I am struggling trying to create my view.

I am looking to automatically create a list of users who have selected a location in their profile (using location module cck field). I want to display this information in a block on a page where I have information on that location.

I am allowing them to select either a country or a country and a city.

In my View I am using:

field: User Name

Filter: User Active

Relationship: Profile

And then I cannot figure out what I need to put for the contextual filter. I have tons of locations so I need something that will automate the process.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why dont you add location to your field in views ? have you tried that?

Comment: I am only looking to show the user name, not the location